# Any way to add actionbar and listview in one single activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

When i open the activity the navigation drawer wont show up. So is there any way that i could add listview and actionbar together in one activity? Would appreciate if anyone could help me. Thanks

```
public class Cart extends ListActivity {

ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cart);


    String[] items = new String[2];
    items[0] = "";


    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(items)));
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    ListView listView = getListView();

    SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener touchListener =
            new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener(
                    listView,
                    new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean canDismiss(int position) {
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss(ListView listView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                            for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                                mAdapter.remove(mAdapter.getItem(position));
                            }
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
    listView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);// ListView scrolling,

}
```

Comment: Used `ListView` and  your activity `extends ActionBarActivity`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just put a ListView inside an ActionBarActivity

```
public class someActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_some);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        YourAdapter listAdapter = new YourAdapter();
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
}
```

Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry.. but once i change it there is some error on    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    ListView listView = getListView();

and there is no ActionBarActivity.. is it because i m using android studio? sorry again not familiar with android still learning on it

Comment: @VincentWeiSheng ive added the adapter to my answer. As for your other quesitions, an action bar activity does not have the methods setListAdapter or getListView, it has to be done like i have shown.

Not sure why your code is not recognising ActionBarActivity either, but it has nothing to do with android studio

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Joe !! I just had to login and give this answer a thumbs up. Solved my problem. Better answer than any I looked up from last few days :)

Here's my piece of code of how I solved it

Using AppCompatActivity as ActionBarActivity seems to be deprecated.

```
public class SelectActivity extends AppCompatActivity /*ListActivity*/ implements OnClickListener {

ListView listView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.select_clothes);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    mList = getListData();
    MyAdapter listAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.row, mList);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```